# Why is Facebook consuming a lot of computer's resources?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cpu, facebook

I have a problem when using the web version of Facebook.

My specs are:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i7-11800H
- **RAM**: 12GB DDR4
- **GPU**: RTX 3050 Laptop 4GB (No MUX Switch)
- All drives are SSDs

An image of task manager of Google Chrome when using web-based Facebook:

[image]

When logging in to Facebook with no other tabs using Chrome, the consumption is completely fine until i fire up the chats. It takes up to nearly 50% of the CPU usage, which quickly heats up my CPU.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this happen when running Chrome in Incognito mode? Does it happen with other browsers than Chrome?

Comment: @harrymc The problem doesn't seem to happen on Firefox but still persist in Chrome Incognito mode.

Comment: The Facebook web interface is notorious for its heavy and inefficient design. A given browser may be more or less optimized for this load. The Chrome design of multiple small processes might be particularly inefficient for such a website as Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

That does seem excessive use of resources, particularly with that fast CPU.

There are ways to [limit Chrome's profligate usage](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/reduce-chrome-memory-cpu-usage/), though:

- In Chrome, in the URL bar, enter `chrome://flags/#high-efficiency-mode-available`. If the flag is available, set it *Enabled*.
- Also search flags for *performance* options, such as `Heap profiling sampling interval`, and, *experimentally*, adjust them.
- In the URL bar, enter `chrome://settings/performance`.

  Enable *Memory Saver*.

  (BTW, this works in other Chrome-based browsers. E.G., `edge://settings` and search on `performance`, which shows *Optimize Performance* options).

You might also consider testing a browser *not* built on Google Chrome, i.e., Firefox.

Comment: Well the problem still persists in Chrome but not in Firefox, might as well switching to Firefox lol